# Standard text colour by subclassing UILabel for use on a storyboard - (IBOutlet)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, subclass

I'm looking to create a standard look and feel within my App, where *some* `UILabel` have a specific `textColor`.

I have several `UILabel` on my `UIViewController`, and in the `viewDidLoad` method I'm calling a function that sets the `textColor` property:

```
[[CHToolKit sharedToolkit] uiLabelAppearanceFeatured:[self IBOLabelStepsRemaining]];
```

`CHToolkit` is a singleton I created for misc tasks.

And, the above works great. But I'm having to do this where-ever I need a `UILabel` with a custom color. Now, it occurred to me that a more prudent course of action would be to subclass the `UILabel`, (I'll call it `CHLabel`) create an instance of my own, and in the init method of it, define the `textColor` there. Then, when adding a new UILabel to my VC, I could instead choose my custom class instead of `UILabel`.

The implementation of my custom `UILabel` is simply as follows:

```
#import "CHToolKit.h"
#import "CHLabel.h"

@implementation CHLabel

- (CHLabel *)init {

    if (self = [super init]) {
        [self setTextColor:kColourDefaultAppColourText];
    }

    return self;

} // init

@end
```

So, when I drag a `UILabel` onto my storyboard (in Interface Builder) I then pick `CHLabel`, (Substituting `UILabel`) from the custom class section. And this, it allows me to do.

Now, when running, I would have expected my `CHLabel` to have had a different color, i.e. the one defined in my custom class. But it **doesn't**. It remains black, or whatever colour has been set in IB.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because in init method no UI objects aren't initialised yet. You need to do it in awakeFromNib method.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    [self setTextColor:kColourDefaultAppColourText];
}
```

Or you can use appearance. Set it in eg. didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method with your subclass:

```
[[CHLabel appearance] setTextColor:kColourDefaultAppColourText];
```

Comment: Many thanks for responding so quickly. I'll give the above a go.

Comment: Hi - fantastic. The awakeFromNib cracked it. I tried the AppDelegate thing but I think adding awakeFromNib is best as this forms part of the object instance code and affects each UILabel on my storyboard with an appropriate colour. Strange in that I had a right good Google-about and searched this site, but to no avail. I would not be surprised if this question has been asked many times though. Thanks for both suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to do this is by using the Appearance Proxy.

You can find the documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/index.html

To change the text color for all UILabels you can use

```
[[UILabel appearance] setTextColor: kColourDefaultAppColourText];
```

in

```
application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

You can also use

```
+ (instancetype)appearanceWhenContainedIn:(Class<UIAppearanceContainer>)ContainerClass
```

to change the appearance of UILabel when is contained in a specific View Controller.

Comment: Interesting - I'll give this a go, too.

Comment: I've given you an up-vote as your suggestion would work, but accepted user1963877 as answered. The awakeFromNib felt simple and located to the object subclass it self. Many thanks though.

Comment: Actually the suggested way from Apple to customize UIKit controls is to use the appearance proxy. You can check the video here: https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/download.action?path=/videos/wwdc_2012__hd/session_216__advanced_appearance_customization_on_ios.mov 
It's from 2012 but you will get the idea